# Best way to control this AC motor

Tags: motor, motor-controller

I am currently in the process of trying to control an AC motor, but I am not sure of what the best way to go about it will be. My main issue is the lack of information I can find about the motor anywhere online.

This motor is a motor from a dryer.  The best information I can find is that it is a WE17M22, or a 5KH26GJ119T.  [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1IIH.jpg) an image of a very similar motor.  Besides that I cant really find much information on the motor, and I don't have a ton of ability to physically look at the motor itself, since it is well enclosed and running in a system.

The dryer that it would come in doesn't seem to have any speed controls, so I can't take any from that.  What do you think would be the easiest/cheapest way to control this motor?  Would something like a triac work for this, or does it need to be a more complex system?

Comment: Phase angle control for universal AC motor would do the job.

Comment: If it's a dryer, it's most likely an induction motor so any controller designed for induction motors should work. Unless it's a really big dryer, the motor is probably 1-2hp max (although it varies with the load on the motor, just like any other motor)

Answer (score 3):

The motor is probably a single-phase induction motor. Induction motors can not be controlled very well by controlling the voltage. Induction motors try to run at their synchronous speed regardless of voltage. Reducing the voltage reduces the amount of torque that the motor can produce, makes it weaker. That tends to make the motor slow down. If the motor is driving a fan or centrifugal pump, considerably less torque is required to run at slower speeds, so the motor can slow down a little and continue to run ok. If the load requires the same torque at any speed, the motor is likely to slow down only a little and then stall and draw high current. Even a fan or pump might not operate at less than 1/2 to 3/4 speed.

You can buy a variable frequency drive (VFD) for a single-phase induction motor, but few manufacturer's make them and they tend to be rather expensive. They are better than voltage reduction devices, but they are not recommended for any type of load except fans and pumps. They also can not be used with capacitor-start motors, only shaded pole or capacitor-run motors.

Comment: **"They also can not be used with capacitor-start motors, only shaded pole or capacitor-run motors."** 

And this is a very important point. Unless you know EXACTLY what type of single phase AC induction motor it is, you cannot assume it is one of the two types that will work with speed controls. Typically those types are NOT used on something like a dryer if it is the drum drive motor, but if it is the fan, **maybe**.

Single phase AC induction motors are not good candidates for speed control as a general rule.

Comment: Further snooping confirms it's a cap start motor. Won't work to do any sort of speed control on that kind of motor. Start over. What do you need to do? Why do you need to control speed, or do you?